# `AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'Handler' in PySpark3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

When I import `from pyspark import SparkFiles`, I got the error `AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'Handler'`.

Python version: 3.8.5
Spark version: 3.0.0
pyspark version3.0.1

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your python version is likely wrong or you have some messed up packages.

I have Spark 3.0.1 installed, with Python 3.7.3.

The import works with no problems.

Perhaps you can try reinstalling Python and setting the environmental variable `PYSPARK_PYTHON`.